# web service for mobile application in yii

Tags: php, web-services, yii

In my Yii web application I want to write a web service for mobile application. I create a url for access student details with GET method. That I want to change GET method to POST method or PUT method. My url is,

```
url/index.php/user/login/studentdetails/?username=demo
```

I am getting this username from client side and giving the response from server side to client side in json format. 
My code is,

```
 public function actionStudentdetails() {

        if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
            $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $_GET['username']));
            $usertypeid = $user->usertypeid;
            if ($usertypeid === '1') {
                $studentid = $user->userid;
            } else if ($usertypeid === '3') {
                $guardianid = $user->userid;
                $studentid = $_GET['studentid'];
            } else {
                $employeemasterid = $user->userid;
            }
            $student = Student::model()->findByPk($studentid);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $response["student_admissionno"] = $student->student_admissionno;
            $response["student_firstname"] = $student->student_firstname;
            $response["student_middlename"] = $student->student_middlename;
            $response["student_lastname"] = $student->student_lastname;
            $response["student_admissiondate"] = $student->student_admissiondate;
            $response["student_dob"] = $student->student_dob;
            $response["student_gender"] = $student->student_gender;
            $response["student_religion"] = $student->student_religion;
            $response["student_caste"] = $student->student_caste;
            $response["student_address1"] = $student->student_address1;
            $response["student_address2"] = $student->student_address2;
            $response["student_city"] = $student->student_city;
            $response["student_state"] = $student->student_state;

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "success";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Read this article:- https://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Do you want to return different results/functionality depending on the HTTP method?

Comment: My problem is how to change get method to post method?. Is this change in client side or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code for webserivce. you can used any method GET or POST Method of data posting in server side.

**StudentController.php**

```
public function actionStudentdetails() {
    $json_data = array();
    $params = isset($_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST: "";
    if (!empty($params)) {
        $username = $params['username'];
        if($username == "") {
            $json_data['success'] = false;
            $json_data['message'] = 'Username are required.';
        } else {
            $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $params['username']));
            $usertypeid = $user->usertypeid;
            if ($usertypeid === '1') {
                $studentid = $user->userid;
            } else if ($usertypeid === '3') {
                $guardianid = $user->userid;
                $studentid = $_GET['studentid'];
            } else {
                $employeemasterid = $user->userid;
            }
            $student = Student::model()->findByPk($studentid);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $json_data["student_admissionno"] = $student->student_admissionno;
            $json_data["student_firstname"] = $student->student_firstname;
            $json_data["student_middlename"] = $student->student_middlename;
            $json_data["student_lastname"] = $student->student_lastname;
            $json_data["student_admissiondate"] = $student->student_admissiondate;
            $json_data["student_dob"] = $student->student_dob;
            $json_data["student_gender"] = $student->student_gender;
            $json_data["student_religion"] = $student->student_religion;
            $json_data["student_caste"] = $student->student_caste;
            $json_data["student_address1"] = $student->student_address1;
            $json_data["student_address2"] = $student->student_address2;
            $json_data["student_city"] = $student->student_city;
            $json_data["student_state"] = $student->student_state;

            $json_data['success'] = true;
            $json_data['message'] = "Data found Successful.";
        }
    } else {
      $json_data['success'] = false;
      $json_data['message'] = "Please try again.";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: But in post method not getting any params like username and password. why?. How resolve this problem?:(

Comment: how to get username via url (POST, GET and REQUEST) method ? username is necessary for get student details?

Comment: you can view above code perfactly. 
execulate your code url/index.php/user/login/studentdetails/?username=demo
your parameter is GET or POST its work it.

Comment: I want to get username with post method and url like url/index.php/user/login/studentdetails. Here not getting any parameters with post method

Comment: you can review this screenshot for execute webservice :  [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/c4tvex)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120803/discussion-between-nikunj-rathod-and-arya).